# How do I disable "add to home screen" pwa on iPhone/Safari?

Tags: ios, iphone, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari, service-worker

[image: please I want to disable this option]

The picture below gives you a clearer view. I need to remove that option to add to home screen on my website and I need to disable it.

Comment: I believe that is for every website as a feature for the user. They do not give you the ability to remove it.

Comment: @Mathias I think you are right. I tested with several websites and I still got the option

Comment: I think this is internally handled by the browser (Safari in this case), so you should check its documentation in case that there is some configuration to allow this (which I think not). Also, take a look of those meta-headers for Safari which overrides some features (like the normal zooming).